# how to resolve issue with autoYAST file

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse

I am trying to install SUSE 12 service pack 3 using autoYAST file. I got an error when screen shows "configuring lan" as

> Augeas parsing/serializing error: Failed to match {/ipaddr/ = /[^\001-\004\t\n #]+/}{ /canonical/ = /[^\001-\004\t\n #]+/ }{ /alias/ = /[^\001-\004\t\n # }*{{ /#comment with tree
>   at /usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/hosts.aug:17.17-21.33
>   caller: /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cfa-8.6.1/lib/cfa/augeas_parser.rb

Comment: Please add more details to your question (edit it, don't comment). What do you mean yast file, are you trying to install via autoyast? At which step does it fail? Where did you get that output from?

Comment: Please add the respective autoyast section for the network configuration to your original question (in code tags).